# Alert Nuget server to update my package

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

I'm hosting private repository for Nuget libraries. Always I update any library to a newer version and go to Manage Nuget Packages I can't see "update" button. There's only one option, to install.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update a nuget package in your project you should go to updates tab in the packages manager. If the newest package was published to your private repository, you should be albe to see this version. Click it and press update button.

[image]